FSCalendar Coordinator class in SwiftUI doesn't update States
Explanation for reproducing:
I'm using FSCalendar to display a calendar in my SwiftUI app. When a date is tapped I display a sheet on my CalendarView.swift. I have events for some dates and when those dates are tapped I modify the sheet and display the details of the event. These events are CoreData entities called Birth and they have a date (Date) and name (String) item inside. When the calendars didSelect function is triggered I check if any event date matches the tapped date. After tapped the date is stored in a state at CalendarView.swift called selectedDate the state is sent to the CalendarViewRepresentable as a binding. If the date matches any event date I set the selectedItems state to the item in an array and add the other events to the selectedItems array if it matched with more then one event. (FYI: I'm testing on IOS 17.5 both simulator and real device, CalendarView.swift is inside a WindowGroup >> TabView)
Problem:
When a date is tapped in the calendar it doesn't update the selectedDate and selectedItems states the first time. They stay in their initial values (in my case nil is the initial value set on CalendarView.swift). However when I tap again on the same date or some other date it starts working fine and shows the right date.
Codes:
CalendarView.swift
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct CalendarView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext
    
    @State var entries: [Birth] = []
    @State var selectedDate: Date? = nil
    @State var selectedItems: [Birth]? = nil
    @State var presentSelection: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        CalendarViewRepresentable(items: $entries, selectedDate: $selectedDate, selectedItems: $selectedItems, presentSelection: $presentSelection)
            .onAppear {
                fetchBirths()
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $presentSelection, content: {
                if selectedItems != nil {
                    Text(selectedDate?.description ?? "Date not found")
                    Text(String(describing: selectedItems!.first!.name))
                        .presentationDetents([.height(170)])
                        .presentationCornerRadius(20)
                } else {
                    Text(String(describing: selectedItems?.count))
                    Text(selectedDate?.description ?? "Date not found")
                        .presentationDetents([.height(170)])
                        .presentationCornerRadius(20)
                }
            })
    }
    
    private func fetchBirths() {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Birth> = Birth.fetchRequest()
        request.relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching = ["group"]
        do {
            let results = try viewContext.fetch(request)
            self.entries = results
        } catch {
            print("Error fetching data: \(error)")
        }
    }
}

Calendar.swift (CalendarViewRepresentable)
import SwiftUI
import FSCalendar

struct CalendarViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    
    typealias UIViewType = FSCalendar
    
    var calendar = FSCalendar()
    
    @Binding var items: [Birth]
    @Binding var selectedDate: Date?
    @Binding var selectedItems: [Birth]?
    @Binding var presentSelection: Bool
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> FSCalendar {
        calendar.delegate = context.coordinator
        calendar.dataSource = context.coordinator
        
        // Appearance
        calendar.appearance.todayColor = UIColor(named: "todayBGColor")
        calendar.appearance.titleTodayColor = .accent
        calendar.appearance.titleFont = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
        calendar.appearance.titleWeekendColor = .darkGray
        calendar.appearance.selectionColor = UIColor(named: "selectionDateBG")
        calendar.appearance.titleSelectionColor = UIColor(named: "selectionDateFG")
        calendar.appearance.eventDefaultColor = .accent
        calendar.appearance.eventSelectionColor = .accent
        calendar.appearance.imageOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 5)
        calendar.appearance.eventOffset = CGPoint(x: 15.5, y: 3.5)
        calendar.appearance.weekdayTextColor = .accent
        calendar.appearance.borderRadius = 0.65
        calendar.appearance.headerDateFormat = "MMMM"
        calendar.appearance.headerMinimumDissolvedAlpha = 0.1
        calendar.appearance.headerTitleFont = .systemFont(
            ofSize: 27,
            weight: .black)
        calendar.appearance.headerTitleColor = .label
        calendar.appearance.titleDefaultColor = .label

        calendar.firstWeekday = 2
        calendar.scrollDirection = .vertical
        calendar.scope = .month
        calendar.clipsToBounds = false
        
        return calendar
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: FSCalendar, context: Context) {}
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject,
                       FSCalendarDelegate, FSCalendarDataSource {
        var parent: CalendarViewRepresentable
        
        func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) { // <<<<< SELECTION MADE HERE
            parent.presentSelection = false
            parent.selectedItems = nil
            
            for item in parent.items {
                if item.date! === date { // "===" Date extension in the code below
                    if parent.selectedItems == nil {
                        parent.selectedItems = [item]
                    } else {
                        parent.selectedItems?.append(item)
                    }
                }
            }
            
            parent.selectedDate = date
            parent.presentSelection = true
        }
        
        func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar,
                      numberOfEventsFor date: Date) -> Int { // Sets event dots
            let today = Date()
            let eventDates: [Date] = parent.items.map { item in
                let daysLeft = daysToDate(date: item.date)
                return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: daysLeft, to: today)!
            }
            var eventCount = 0
            eventDates.forEach { eventDate in
                if eventDate.formatted(date: .complete,
                                       time: .omitted) == date.formatted(
                                        date: .complete, time: .omitted){
                    if eventCount != 2 {
                        eventCount += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            return eventCount
        }
        
        func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar,
                      imageFor date: Date) -> UIImage? {
            
            var image: UIImage? = nil
            
            let _: [Date?] = parent.items.map { item in
                let daysLeft = daysToDate(date: item.date)
                let itemDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: daysLeft, to: Date())!
                if itemDate === date {
                    var data = item.picture
                    if item.picture == nil {
                        data = Data()
                    }
                    image = data!.toSmallAvatarImage()
                }
                return nil
            }
            
            return image
        }
        
        func maximumDate(for calendar: FSCalendar) -> Date {
            var dt = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: Date())
            dt.day = Int(dt.day ?? 0) - 1
            let start = Calendar.current.date(from: dt)!
            return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: 12, to: start)!
        }
        
        func minimumDate(for calendar: FSCalendar) -> Date {
            let dt = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: Date())
            return Calendar.current.date(from: dt)!
        }
        
        init(_ parent: CalendarViewRepresentable) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
    }
}

Date extension
static func ===(first: Date, second: Date) -> Bool {
        let firstDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month, .day], from: first)
        let secondDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month, .day], from: second)
        
        return firstDate.day == secondDate.day && firstDate.month == secondDate.month
    }

